# Dependency property default value does not show in properties browser

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom window class that inherits from window class. In custom class I defined a dependency property and set its default value. But the default value does not show in property browser panel of visual studio. How can I fix this problem
Best regards.

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    [Description("Some descriptions")]
    public class FlatWindow:Window
    { 
        public FlatWindow()
        {
            if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                this.HasCloseButton = true;
            }
        }

        [Description("my description"), Category("my Properties"), Browsable(true),DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool HasCloseButton
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HasCloseButtonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HasCloseButtonProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasCloseButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HasCloseButton", typeof(bool), typeof(FlatWindow),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true,FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
}
}
```

[Screen shot from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npWJo.png)

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow. what should I do?

Comment: @Yuvette Colomb understood !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency Property (DP) appear in Visual Studio property browser when you use :

- Custom control
- Control
- UserControl

Unfortunately the properties box now show DP when you use "Window"

You can see on msdn more on [Dependency Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties)